# Rendering state json in React

Tags: json, reactjs

I am unable to get the application to render this simple state data. It seems to me that i can't get the information in the render part to understand the data json.

this.state.data should contain the object since I can console.log it when it has done it's fetch.

I assumed that the object would be able to render as it is

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
var $ = require('jquery');

class App extends Component {

  loadData() {
    console.log("loading data");
        fetch('https://api.nytimes.com/svc/movies/v2/reviews/search.json?api-key=f90d8b6f90d04bb5bbbeb2f241155ce7&query=star wars')
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                this.setState({data: data });
        })
            .catch(err => console.error(this.props.url, err.toString()))
  }

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { data: [] };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log('GrandChild did mount.');

      this.loadData()
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h1 className="App-title">Welcome to React</h1>
        </header>
        <p className="App-intro">
          To get started, edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
        <ul>
                {this.state.data(function(name, index){
                    return <li key={ index }>{name}</li>;
                  })}
            </ul>
      </div>


    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several errors - see fixes and comments in code:

```js
class App extends React.Component {

  loadData() {
    console.log("loading data");
    fetch('https://api.nytimes.com/svc/movies/v2/reviews/search.json?api-key=f90d8b6f90d04bb5bbbeb2f241155ce7&query=star wars')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        this.setState({ data: data });
      })
      .catch(err => console.error(this.props.url, err.toString()))
  }

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { data: null }; // initialize with null
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log('GrandChild did mount.');

    this.loadData()
  }

  render() {
    const { data } = this.state;
    return (
      <ul>
        // if data not loaded null will render nothing
        // if data is not null, we iterate data.results with map
        {data && data.results.map(function (film, index) {
          // film is an object, just one or more properties to render
          return <li key={index}>{film.headline}</li>;
        })}
      </ul>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  app
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Small error amount to unusable code. Thanks for fixing. Just note that ReactDOM does not work. It needs "export default App;"

Comment: As you can see I've removed everything that is not related to the problem. I can't use import in the example, so I've just rendered the component.